# 3Setup a single network with Devolo and ZTE?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I am trying to setup my home network. I have an ISP router (ZTE) and I bought two Devolo devices to extend my network.

I can't understand what it is happening. I have a device with a fixed ip for the local network. I am able to access the device from anywhere if I write the ip in a browser

The device/ip is not listed in the ZTE devices `WLAN Device List` and if I have an application that wants to access this device, it does not discover the IP

The devices that are connected to Devolo seems to be hidden from the `WLAN Device List`

Comment: Verify the is and the case what is are fetched in that case

Comment: @djdomi thank your for your comment, I updated the question, now it is a more specific about what it is happening